# axiomantic semantic..what are the weakest preconditon?

Tags: semantics

i was studying axiomantic semantic which is really pain in my ass. everything was so far great untill i met these questions.  i was stuck at the 2 Question which has 'and' in the postcondition.

what are the weakest precondition?

1)
`if (x > y)
        c = x * 2 + 4
    else
        a = x + 4;
    {a > 4 and c < 6}`

2)`if (x > y)
        e = x * 2 + 4
    else
        f = x + 5;
    {f > 4 and e > 6}`

i've never seen postcondition with the 'and' , it was pretty confusing.
because when i tried to figure out the first one

(precondition for if)

`a>4 and 2x+4<6
  a>4 and 2x<2
  a>4 and x<1`

(pre condtion for else)

`x+4 >4 and c<6
   x>0 and c<6`

i couldn't apply the rule of consequence because there are three variables and x has different direction of comparison symbol , which is hard to figure out which one is the stronger one, or weaker.
can anyone help this poor computer noob :( ?